# Responsive desktop app using Kony

Tags: css, media-queries, temenos-quantum, responsive

we have a mobile application developed using Kony. We are trying to port the same to desktop version. Everything goes well but there are small challenges wrt UI i.e., responsive UI. Since I am new to Kony please guide me if there is a way to include media queries in a Kony application or what could be trick to make the app responsive on browser.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by media queries? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I need to know how do we make a desktop version of an application developed using Kony platform responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Kony does not currently support media queries to say "for screens of this size use this css rules". Remember in Kony your styling is done with skinning, not CSS3. Skins do translate into css for web apps, but that's a different story.

In Kony the approach is different. You design your forms for different screen sizes based on the type of mobile device: Mobile phone, tablet, desktop, watch, etc.

If you come from a web development background like I do, you might even be expecting a grid system like in Bootstrap or Foundation. But bear in mind that the real value of responsive design is not having to worry about the resolution of the screen, except **Kony already gives you this through the use of Dp units** instead of pixels. So the same mobile form design will adapt to any mobile device resolution. The same tablet form will adapt to any tablet resolution and so on.

For different device types, the premise is that your desktop and mobile screens will most likely be very different, or even start alike but evolve differently over time.

So the solution is to just copy your form from the "Mobile" subtree (right-click>copy) and paste it under the "Desktop" subtree. Then you'll be able to edit them independently.

I hope this helps.

[image]

**Edit:**

Starting with Visualizer V8 SP2 [Kony does support Responsive Design](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#Responsive_Design_8_2.htm).